# Lifting Elements from Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups

The problem:

> $\textbf{(Pinter, Abstract Algebra 2nd Ed, Chapter 16 Section O)}$
>
> Let $G$ is a finite abelian group, and let $a$ be an element of $G$ such that ord($a$) is a multiple of ord($x$) for every $x\in G$. Let $H = \langle a\rangle$. We will prove:
>
> For every $x \in G$, there is some $y\in G$ such that $Hx = Hy$ and ord($y$) = ord($Hy$).
>
> This means that every cosets of $H$ contains an element $y$ whose order is the same as the coset's order.
>
> Let $x$ be any element in $G$, and let ord($a$) = $t$, ord($x$) = $s$, and ord($Hx$) = $r$.
>
> 1. Explain why $r$ is the least positive integer such that $x^r$ equals some power of $a$, say $x^r = a^m$.
> 2. Deduce from our hypothesis that $r$ divides $s$, and $s$ divides $t$. Thus, we may write $s = ru$ and $t = sv$, so in particular, $t = ruv$.
> 3. Explain why $a^{mu} = e$, and why it follows that $mu = tz$ for some integer $z$. Then explain why $m = rvz$.
> 4. Setting $y = xa^{-vz}$, prove that $Hx = Hy$ and ord($y$) $= r$, as required.

My attempt:

1) It is given that $(Hx)^r = H(x^r) = H$. Since $Hc = H$ iff $c\in H$, it must be the case that $x^r\in H.$

Thus, $x^r$ is some power of $a$ and denote that power of $a$ to be $a^m$. Therefore, $x^r = a^m$.

2) Clearly $(Hx)^s = H(x^s) = He = H$. So, $s$ is a multiple of the order of $Hx$ and $r|s$.

Since the order of $a$ is a multiple of the order of <s>b</s> $x$ by hypothesis, $s|t$.

3) We know that $x^r = a^m$ and $x^s = e$. So if we take $x^s = x^{ru} = (x^r)^u = (a^m)^u = a^{mu}$. Thus, $a^{mu} = e$. Now we observe that $mu \geqslant t$, since the order of $a$ is $t$. So $mu$ is a multiple of $t$ so $mu = tz$ for some $z\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now observe that $mu = tz\to mu = ruvz\to m = rvz$ by O2.

4) Let $y = xa^{-vz}$, then $Hy = Hxa^{-vz} = Ha^{-vz} x = Hx$ because $G$ and $H$ are abelian and $a^{-vz}\in H$. Thus, $Hx = Hy$.

Now suppose the order of $y$ is $r$, then $(xa^{-vz})^r = (x^r a^{-rvz}) = a^ma^{-rvz} = a^{rvz}a^{-rvz} = a^0 = e$. Therefore, the ord($y$) $= r$.

Corrections or changes are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1: You have explained why $x^r$ is a power of $a$, but not why it is the *least* positive power of $x$ that is a power of $a$.

For 2: I assume you mean $x$ in stead of $b$? Otherwise your argument is fine.

For 3: It is not true that $mu\geq t$. What you need is that $t\mid mu$, then your further reasoning is again correct.

For 4: Perfect!

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: I just noticed you already explain why $m=rvz$ in your answer to question 3, so never mind my comment on this.